# Crear Class con Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio, class

Estoy utilizando android studio 3.0.1 y estoy intentando crear una nueva clase en mi proyecto App-> java->com.valhondo.delgado.mibasedatos. Aqui intento crear una nueva java class.

```
Name: DBHelper
Kind: Class
superclass:
Interface:
Package: com.valhondo.delgado.mibasedatos
Visibilyty: public
Modifiers: None
```

Cuando le doy a OK me sale este error:

> Unable to parse template "Class" Error menssage. This template did not
>   produce a Java class or an interface

¿Qué me falta por poner y cómo lo pongo para que se cree la clase?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué hará esa clase? Si es una `Activity`, un `Service` un `Fragment`... o algo así, debes seleccionar uno de esos tipos específicos, más abajo en el último grupo de opciones. [Puedes ver algunas respuestas a esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45497266/5587982) para resolver  el problema.

Comment: Esta clase la abro para manejar una base de datos sqlite . Solo hay otra opcion mas abajo que es Show Select  Overrides  Dialog pero solo se puede seleccionar o deseleccionar, pero sale el mismo error.

Comment: Es un problema de plantilla que deberás corregir. Revisa el enlace de mi primer comentario, pues ahí dan varias soluciones al problema. Pero como primer paso, asegúrate de que AS está **totalmente** actualizado a su última versión.